# Delete lines based on two tables

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration, pentaho-data-integration

I have one problem, where i have one main table one other table. I have in one table (Accidents), attribute named **Accident_ID** (Values goes like this 1,4,7,10 and so on)

In other table named casualties, i have the same attribute **Accident_ID** (But values here goes like this 1,2,2, 3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10, 11 and so on). => There are several same ID-s because each Accident can have more Casualties.

The question is how can i delete in table casualties lines, which don't have same ID-s as in table Accidents (So i want to delete lines in table Casualties with ID-s 2,3,5,6,8,9,11 etc) => i have like 100k ID-s so i can't do manually.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `Merge Diff` step. It compares two streams (or tables) and tell the rows which are added, deleted, modified or identical. Then `Filter` out the rows you do not want.

Comment: He's asking how to delete, not filter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PDI to do that. A simple SQL query can solve your problem.

```
DELETE FROM Casualties WHERE Accident_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Accident_ID FROM Accidents)
```